# Implementing generic Retrofit interface for dynamic routes in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am currently trying to refactor my Androïd project using the very neat Retrofit library. Although I have already some working examples on other project using this library, I am trying to push my integration even further so that I can generate dynamic routes.

To do so, I have started coding an interface using Retrofit which looks like this:

```
public interface RestServices<T> {

@GET("{route_name}")
List<T> getObjects(@Path("route_name") String route, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);

@GET("{route_name}/{id}")
T getObject(@Path("route_name") String route, @Path("id") String id, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);

@POST("{route_name}")
T postObject(@Path("route_name") String route, @Body T object);

@PUT("{route_name}/{id}")
T putObject(@Path("route_name") String route, @Path("id") String id, @Body T object);

}
```

Basically this calls the basic routes I am using in my app for each service and all I need from this interface a class implementing this interface in order to generate the routes dyncamically using the class name of my models bound to my service.

```
public abstract class RestProviderImpl<T> extends RestProvider<RestServices<T>> {

protected abstract String getClassName();
protected abstract Class<RestServices<T>> getProvider();

protected String getMethod() {
    String className = getClassName();
    String res = TextUtils.join("_", className.split("(?=[A-Z])"));
    return res.substring(1).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
}

protected String getPluralizedMethod() {
    return getMethod() + "s";
}

public List<T> getObjects(Map<String, String> options) {
    return getService(getProvider()).getObjects(getPluralizedMethod(), options);
}

public T getObject(String id, Map<String, String> options) {
    return getService(getProvider()).getObject(getPluralizedMethod(), id, options);
}

public T postObject(T object) {
    return getService(getProvider()).postObject(getPluralizedMethod(), object);
}

public T putObject(String id, T object) {
    return getService(getProvider()).putObject(getPluralizedMethod(), id, object);
}

}
```

From then on I would declare all other relevant services as an extension of this interface. I could add all specific routes into these `services`.

```
public interface UserService extends RestServices<User> {}
```

However I bumped into an exception into the Retrofit library saying that this in unsafe to extend from another interface (which is basically what I wanted to do...).

Is there something wrong with what I'm trying to achieve? Could you give me some tips so that I could do something similar?

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/504

Comment: I sure saw that open issue but I'm not sure that just disabling this exception by using the forked library is the right thing to do as the developers did not explained plainly why they added this limitation.

Comment: The quoted comment seems to explain the developers' point of view quite clearly.

Comment: @ptitvinou update https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/3145, once this get merged there won't be issue any more.